# expected identifier before "{" token

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit

I'm trying to compile the following code however I get an error on the indicated line:

```
#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods 

//**error expected identifier before  "{"  token**
-(void)locationmanager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation  *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *) 
{

MKCoordinateSpan span; 
span.latitudeDelta = 0,2;
span.longitudeDelta = 0,2;

MKCoordinateRegion region; 
region.span = span;
region.center = newLocation.coordinate;

[viewController.mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];
viewController.mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;

viewController.latitude.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Xf", newLocation.coordinate.latitude]
viewController.longitude.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Xf", newLocation.coordinate.longitude]

}

@end
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please phrase your post as a question in the future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an argument name before the trailing `{` on the first line, e.g.

```
... fromLocation:(CLLocation *)fromLocation {
```

Comment: Looks like he is missing semi-colon too viewController.latitude.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Xf", newLocation.coordinate.latitude]
viewController.longitude.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Xf", newLocation.coordinate.longitude]

Comment: Indeed, but not the cause of the error in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as it says, you have

```
-(void)locationmanager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation  *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *) 
{
```

you are missing the  argument fromLocation name, the thing should be

```
-(void)locationmanager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation  *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)someName
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing semicolons on the last two assignment statements.

Comment: This is not the cause of the error about which the OP is asking, however.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `0,2` with `0.2` (with a dot), and add `;` at the end of the two last calls.